# How to describe a shopping dispute?

Tags: word-choice

I try to state a disagreement in a deal, or someone violates the deal or contract. I did a web search on **shopping dispute**, and got only 8000 results.  The number implies that it is not a common usage to describe it, while correct usage usually comes out with millions of results. How to describe it?

> Dispute: a disagreement or argument; a territorial dispute between the two countries

Comment: Try "consumer dispute" or "contract dispute".

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It is very helpful and the phrase comes out with 150,000 results. In addition, it seems to describe a costumer, who is not satisfied with the service. Can it also state a service provider or dealer who is not satisfied with the consumer?

Comment: "Contract dispute" works in both directions. "Consumer dispute" usually implies a dissatisfied customer, not a dissatisfied retailer or dealer.

Comment: If there is a violation of the terms of the agreement (contract) or one of the parties fails to carry out required duties, the legal term is *breach*. It can be used in the phrases *breach of [the] contract, breach of duties, breach of [his] obligations,* and similar constructions. This is not usually used to describe informal relationships, except in the phrase *breach of decorum*, such as a customer throwing a hissy fit in the aisle.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a formal contract and one party or the other is claiming that the other has not lived up to the terms of the contract, that is a "contract dispute". Usually we use the term "contract dispute" when there is some ambiguity in the contract that both parties can make at least a plausible claim that they are right. If someone is just ignoring the contract, if it said he was supposed to pay $X or do such-and-such work and he just refuses, that's generally called "breach of contract" rather than a "contract dispute".

In cases where there is no formal contract, like when you go to a store and buy something and then claim you didn't get your money's worth in one way or another, that's a "consumer complaint".

Off the top of my head I can't think of any other related terms, but I'm sure lawyers have a boatload of them. :-)

Comment: "customer complaint" is a synonym for "consumer complaint".